# THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR crash in 2.3 android emulator

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

i have to use THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR in AsynTask and i know it's belong API 11 and above. with this code i checked it:

```
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                    new init().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
                } else {
                    new init().execute();
                }
```

but when i run my app in 2.3 device i get error around THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR!! in above code i say there is no need too run it in 2.3 devices! i get this error:

```
10-04 14:00:26.914: W/dalvikvm(728): VFY: unable to resolve static field 33 (THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR) in Landroid/os/AsyncTask;
```

what is that? how i can fix it?

UPDATE: whole logcat:

```
10-04 16:27:50.254: D/dalvikvm(760): DexOpt: couldn't find static field
10-04 16:27:50.254: W/dalvikvm(760): VFY: unable to resolve static field 33 (THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR) in Landroid/os/AsyncTask;
10-04 16:27:50.254: D/dalvikvm(760): VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x000d
10-04 16:27:50.254: D/dalvikvm(760): VFY: dead code 0x000f-0014 in Lcom/app/weatherclock/MainActivity$10;.run ()V

10-04 16:27:51.124: D/dalvikvm(760): GC_CONCURRENT freed 174K, 45% free 3217K/5831K, external 1608K/2119K, paused 7ms+6ms
10-04 16:27:51.234: W/webcore(760): Can't get the viewWidth after the first layout
10-04 16:27:51.244: W/dalvikvm(760): JNI WARNING: jarray 0x40556118 points to non-array object (Ljava/lang/String;)
10-04 16:27:51.254: I/dalvikvm(760): "WebViewCoreThread" prio=5 tid=9 NATIVE
10-04 16:27:51.254: I/dalvikvm(760):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x4050d6b0 self=0x216c78
10-04 16:27:51.254: I/dalvikvm(760):   | sysTid=768 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=2190768
10-04 16:27:51.254: I/dalvikvm(760):   | schedstat=( 339530872 394652888 76 )
10-04 16:27:51.254: I/dalvikvm(760):   at android.webkit.LoadListener.nativeFinished(Native Method)
10-04 16:27:51.264: I/dalvikvm(760):   at android.webkit.LoadListener.nativeFinished(Native Method)
10-04 16:27:51.264: I/dalvikvm(760):   at android.webkit.LoadListener.tearDown(LoadListener.java:1200)
10-04 16:27:51.264: I/dalvikvm(760):   at android.webkit.LoadListener.handleEndData(LoadListener.java:721)
10-04 16:27:51.264: I/dalvikvm(760):   at android.webkit.LoadListener.handleMessage(LoadListener.java:219)
10-04 16:27:51.264: I/dalvikvm(760):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-04 16:27:51.264: I/dalvikvm(760):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
10-04 16:27:51.264: I/dalvikvm(760):   at android.webkit.WebViewCore$WebCoreThread.run(WebViewCore.java:629)
10-04 16:27:51.264: I/dalvikvm(760):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
10-04 16:27:51.274: E/dalvikvm(760): VM aborting
```

Comment: I don't know the answer to this problem, but I can strongly advice against the emulator.

Answer (score 2):

It's just a *warning* and you can ignore it.

The Dalvik class loader found a reference to a field that is missing and emitted a warning. The `SDK_INT` conditional above prevents that part of the code from running on pre-Honeycomb.

(The `HONEYCOMB` constant is a `static final` primitive that gets inlined at compile time and does not need to be resolved at class loading time.)

Comment: but after that i get this error:  10-04 13:59:33.774: E/dalvikvm(683): VM aborting .  and my app terminates!

Comment: @Fcoder That's probably caused by something else. Any exceptions in logcat?

Comment: This is the answer to your question but I don't know the solution to your problem. Quick googling shows that other people have seen similar errors: https://www.google.com/search?q=W%2Fwebcore+Can't+get+the+viewWidth+after+the+first+layout